# Convert Bootable DVD to DMG

Tags: startup, dmg, bootable-disk, dvd

i want to convert my `Sierra` DVD to a `DMG` file , so i could install it on non-mac device ( PC ).

I used `Disk Utilities` but not worked...

Is it possible to do this ? or i **Have** to download the source from AppStore ?

Comment: There is no such thing as a Sierra DVD installation disk.

Answer (score 1):

https://kb.wisc.edu/page.php?id=7058

You need to make a disk image as explained in the provided link, however there is far more involved in making a Hackintosh, and it comes down to having the right hardware and understanding how to apply information about how to do it correctly.

Check compatibility: http://www.hackintosh.com/#hackintosh_compatible
You'll need to follow this guide: http://www.hackintosh.com/

I'd recommend watching some YouTube videos and while I haven't tried to make a Hackintosh in a few years, I'd high suggest that you should not expect it to work perfectly and it does require a decent amount of work to make it work